# Replace duplicate value in each column as as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table similar to this

[image]

I want to **replace all the duplicate values in first TWO** columns to be replaced with a null *i.e* an output similar to this

[image]

Added the html code below for reference

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table >
   <thead>
      <tr >
         <th>ABBEY     </th>
         <th>ANX   </th>
         <th>TPIN</th>
         <th>ACP</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>ABNAMRO   </td>
         <td>ANW   </td>
         <td>TPIN</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>32</td>
         <td>32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>ABNAMROLLC</td>
         <td>MLD   </td>
         <td>TPIN</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>AMHERSTP  </td>
         <td>QPE</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>341</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>RJT</td>
         <td>56</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>QPE   </td>
         <td>TPIN</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>24</td>
         <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>QPP</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>353</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>RJT</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>BAKERGRP  </td>
         <td>JBC</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>ACP</td>
         <td>337</td>
         <td>142</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>GRAM</td>
         <td>RJT</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4gn2a83/2/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. Now your question belongs at elance.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a little something like the following.

The `columnsToProcess` object should specify `true` for the *zero-based* column indices of the columns to process. For your stated requirement to do the first two columns only I could've just used a selector of `"td:lt(2)"` instead, but using an object to specify which columns to process is more versatile, in case, e.g., you later wanted to process the first, fourth, and sixth columns:

```
columnsToProcess = { 0: true, 3: true, 5: true }
```

The `lastVals` object keeps track of the last changed value for each column. There's no need to initialise its elements at all because when we test `lastVals[i]` it will just return `undefined` if not yet initialised, and `undefined` is not equal to any string.

```js
var columnsToProcess = {
  0: true,
  1: true
};
var lastVals = {};
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {     // for each row
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i) {   // for each cell in the current row
    if (!columnsToProcess[i]) return;     // do we care about this column?
    if (this.innerHTML === lastVals[i])   // if value is same as the previous row
      this.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";          // blank out the cell
    else                                  // otherwise
      lastVals[i] = this.innerHTML;       // remember the current value
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>ABBEY</th><th>ANX</th><th>TPIN</th><th>ACP</th><th>4</th><th>3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>ABNAMRO</td><td>ANW</td><td>TPIN</td><td>ACP</td><td>32</td><td>32</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABNAMROLLC</td><td>MLD</td><td>TPIN</td><td>ACP</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AMHERSTP</td><td>QPE</td><td>GRAM</td><td>ACP</td><td>341</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AMHERSTP</td><td>QPE</td><td>GRAM</td><td>RJT</td><td>56</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AMHERSTP</td><td>QPE</td><td>TPIN</td><td>ACP</td><td>24</td><td>19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AMHERSTP</td><td>QPP</td><td>GRAM</td><td>ACP</td><td>353</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>AMHERSTP</td><td>QPP</td><td>GRAM</td><td>RJT</td><td>2</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>BAKERGRP</td><td>JBC</td><td>GRAM</td><td>ACP</td><td>337</td><td>142</td></tr>
    <tr><td>BAKERGRP</td><td>JBC</td><td>GRAM</td><td>RJT</td><td>3</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Left as an exercise for the reader: trimming whitespace before comparing the values, if `"AMHERSTP"` and `"AMHERSTP    "` are supposed to be considered equal.